# node.js refusing connection?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have some node.js code that I am running called app.js When it runs is gives an error saying connection refused?

It is running on plesk so I cannot debug it. I have added the package.json too but maybe I am missing something?

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "socket-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

**app.js:**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');


// Loading the index file . html displayed to the client
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});

// Loading socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// When a client connects, we note it in the console
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A client is connected!');
});


server.listen(8080);
```

**index.html:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Communicating with socket.io!</h1>

    <p><input type="button" value="Poke the server" id="poke" /></p>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

        // The visitor is asked for their username...
        var username = prompt('What\'s your username?');

        // It's sent with the signal "little_newbie" (to differentiate it from "message")
        socket.emit('little_newbie', username);

        // A dialog box is displayed when the server sends us a "message"
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            alert('The server has a message for you: ' + message);
        })

        // When the button is clicked, a "message" is sent to the server
        $('#poke').click(function () {
            socket.emit('message', 'Hi server, how are you?');
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing all you code like this as this will resolve your issues
app.js

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set("view engine","html");


var http = require('http');

//making express server for routes
var server = http.Server(app);




// Loading socket.io
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//index route
//loaded when the website is loaded root route.
app.get('/',function(req,res){
 //specify the path to the directory (assuming both are in the same directory)
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

// When a client connects, we note it in the console
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A client is connected!');

    //message of client side
    socket.on('little_newbie',function(message){
     //give the username in terminal of the connected client
     console.log(message);
     //send a hello to the client from the server.
     io.sockets.emit('message',"Hello "+message);
    })
    //button poke mesage response
    socket.on('message',function(message){
     //print the hello message from the server
     console.log(message)

     //after this you can send a response back to the client as in the above case
     io.sockets.emit('poke',"Hi I am fine ");
    })

});

server.listen(8080);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Socket.io</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Communicating with socket.io!</h1>

    <p><input type="button" value="Poke the server" id="poke" /></p>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('/');

        // The visitor is asked for their username...
        var username = prompt('What\'s your username?');

        // It's sent with the signal "little_newbie" (to differentiate it from "message")
        socket.emit('little_newbie', username);

        // A dialog box is displayed when the server sends us a "message"
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            alert('The server has a message for you: ' + message);
        })

        // When the button is clicked, a "message" is sent to the server
        $('#poke').click(function () {
            socket.emit('message', 'Hi server, how are you?');
        })

        socket.on('poke',function(message){
            alert(message);
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

```html
{
  "name": "socket-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183969/discussion-on-answer-by-jawad-zaheer-node-js-refusing-connection).

Answer (score 0):

There ate no routes configuration , and when you try to ping from browser it won't connect . just like meaning less URI. Try making a route and then calking route from Browser.

Comment: Thanks for that but how do I do that? I am new to node.js and that code came from a tutorial site and doesnt mention anything about routes? Thanks for your help